# Change the text of a UILabel in viewDidLoad() programmatically

Tags: iphone, uilabel

How do I change the text of my UILabel in viewDidLoad method of my view controller?.

My code below does not update the UI.

```
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
                  bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
       if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil 
                         bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
           displayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 230, 40)];
           [self.view addSubview:displayLabel];
       }
       return self;
   }

//
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    displayLabel.text = @"abc";
}
```

Comment: Just as a hint for the future, methods in Objective-C aren't called with a `()` syntax, nor are they named that way. The proper name for this method is `-viewDidLoad`, and, say, `-initWithNibName:bundle:` for the method you are showing at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding the subview in viewDidLoad.

self.view is an IBOutlet and it will not be  loaded into memory at the point that initWithNibName is called, and will be equal to nil.

viewDidLoad is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory.  And as such self.view will point to the view you created in your nib file.

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear {
    displayLabel.text = @"abc";
}

This is ok!